# Difference in definition of Reflexive Relation between Set Theory and Class Theory

Tags: set-theory

The class-theoretical context of this comes from Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* (revised ed., 2010).

Context: self-study.

Consider a relation $R$ on a **set**: $R \subseteq S \times S$

Consider a relation $R'$ on a **class**: $R' \subseteq V \times V$, where $V$ is a basic universe.

Now in the set-theoretical context, $R$ is a **reflexive relation** iff:
$$\forall x \in S: (x, x) \in R$$

However, in the field-theoretical context, $R'$ is a **reflexive relation** iff:
$$\forall x \in \mathrm {Field} (R'): (x, x) \in R'$$

where $\mathrm {Field} (R')$ is defined as the (class) union of the domain and range of $R'$, which are themselves defined as the subclasses of $V$ containing (respectively) the first coordinates of $R'$ and the second coordinates of $R'$.

The latter definition is according to S&F Chapter $4$: Superinduction, Well-Ordering and Choice, $\S 1$: Introduction to Well-Ordering.

This makes the definition of a reflexive relation between classes different from that between sets. But a set is a class. Hence the definitions are inconsistent.

Note further that this has the knock-on effect that if a (class-theoretically-defined) relation is both **symmetric** and **transitive**, then it is as a result **reflexive**.

This is at odds with the standard set-theoretical result that it is **not necessarily the case** that a relation both symmetric and transitive is also reflexive.

How is this resolved?

- Have Smullyan and Fitting made a mistake here?
- Are there sources which define a reflexive relation for class
  theory consistent with that for set theory, in which a reflexive
  relation is defined on a general class $C$ in which, if there exist
  $x \in C$ for which $x$ is not actually in the field of $C$, then the
  relation is specifically not reflexive?
- Is it glossed over or otherwise brushed under the carpet?
- Is it genuinely unimportant in the general scheme of things?

Considering that class theory was specifically invented to address inconsistencies and loose thinking in the whole area of set theory, it would be disappointing to learn that the above is considered a minor enough matter to ignore.

Please comment with requests for clarification if I have explained this insufficiently clearly.

Comment: It seems to me that the book has only the second def.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes this is true, but the question remains. The definition differs from all the other (exclusively set-theoretical) definitions I've seen. Have S&F glossed over something important, or made a mistake, or do they have a *genuine* reason to do it this way? I don't know, which is why I ask the question. I need help in understanding this, like so many other points of technical detail that I have difficulty in finding explanations for. Do you know of any online resources which may be able to offer me such help? It's sometimes hard being self-taught.

Comment: Not very clear your concern... The usual def says: $R$ on $S$ is *reflexive* iff $xRx$ for every $x \in S$. Thus: $S = \text {Dom}(R)$. You concern is about $\text {Ran}(R)$? Usually we have $\text {Ran}(R) \subseteq S$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, that is the usual case, and so $S = \text{Dom}(R)$ emerges as a property of that definition. But S&F define $R$ as reflexive even if $S \ne \text{Dom}(R)$. Thus $\{(1, 1)\} \subseteq \{1, 2\} \times \{1, 2\}$ would be defined as reflexive in S&F because $2$ is not an element of the field of $\{(1,1)\}$ -- inconsistent with the usual set theoretical definition. So you're saying that this discrepancy between S&F's definition and literally every single other definition of a reflexive relation is nothing to worry about?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The point is that *it is not necessarily the case that* $\text{Dom}(R) = S$. It is always the case that $\text{Dom}(R) \subseteq S$ same as it is always the case that $\text{Rng}(R) \subseteq S$.

Comment: The usual def of *reflexive* says "**for every** $x$..." Thus, if we want to be hyper-precise, we have to say : "for every $x \in \text {Dom}(R) : (x,x) \in R$". If $x$ is not in the domain of $R$, obviously $(x, \text ?) \notin R$ whatever $?$ may be.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, to be hyper-precise, the definition of reflexive "for every $x \in \text{Dom} (R): (x, x) \in R$" is **not** the usual definition of reflexive. Because there may be $x \in S$ such that $x \notin \text{Dom}(R)$, in which case $R$ is not reflexive on $S$. While such an $x$ is reflexive on $\text{Dom}(R)$, that is *not the same thing* as $x$ being reflexive on $S$. Why is it totally okay to gloss over what looks on the surface like an **APPALLING** mistake in S&F?

Comment: If we want to be precise, the "usual£ def of *relation* in axiomatic set theory does not start with $R \subseteq S \times T$ or similar. It starts with the def of *ordered pair* and then says: $R$ is a *relation* iff $R= \forall r (r \in R \to \exists x\exists y (r=(x,y))$. Then we define $\text {Dom}(R) = \{ x \mid \exists y (x,y) \in R \}$

Comment: And now we define *reflexivity* : $R \text { is reflexive in } A \text { iff } \forall x (x \in A \to (x,x) \in R)$

Comment: So, when "laymen" say that $R$ is defined on $S$, they have to take care of this point in defining reflexivity: either they assume explicitly that $\text {Dom}(R)=S$ or they have to specify that $R$ is reflexive on $\text {Dom}(R)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "... the "usual£ def of relation in axiomatic set theory does not start with R⊆S×T or similar. It starts with the def of ordered pair and then says: ..." That is *not* how it is defined in S&F. That has "a relation $R$ is nothing more nor less than a subclass of the Cartesian product $V \times V$." Then (later in the book) it goes on to define $R$ as reflexive by limiting it to the **field** of $R$.